# Accessing Methods of Android Compound Component

Tags: android, view, methods, components

I've defined a Compound Component that consists of two `TextView`s and a single `EditText`. In the class for this Compound Component I've defined a getter method that returns the `EditText` view so that I can set an `OnFocusChangeListener` to this `EditText` in the `onCreate` method of my activity.

However, in the `onFocusChange` method I need access to some of the methods defined in the Compound Component class, but all I have available is the view object. Is it possible to get access to these methods in the Compound Component class? Perhaps I should be rethinking the code's structure?

The compound component class (simplified for brevity):

```
public class CompondComponent extends LinearLayour {

    private EditText editText;

    public CompoundComponent(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
         // Inflate layout etc.

         editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.compound_component);
    }

    // getter
    public EditText getEditText() {
        return editText;
    }

}
```

The activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnFocusChangeListener {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);

        CompoundComponent cc1 = (CompoundComponent) findViewById(R.id.myComponent1);
        cc1.getEditText().setOnFocusChangeListener(this);

        CompoundComponent cc2 = (CompoundComponent) findViewById(R.id.myComponent2);
        cc2.getEditText().setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
    }

    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean focus) {

        // need to invoke cc's methods here, i.e. for cc1 or cc2

    }


}
```

Would really appreciate any hints. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make `cc1` and `cc2` Activity's fields and define whatever methods you need in `CompoundComponent`,

Comment: Thanks Alex. But how do I know whether to invoke `cc1` or `cc2` in `onFocusChange` of the main activity? i.e., onFocusChange is called when either `cc1` or `cc2` loses focus; how do I know which one the event ocurred on?

Comment: public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean focus) {

    CompoundComponent cc = (CompoundComponent)v;

    cc.doSomething();

}

Comment: Thanks, but computer says no. The `CompoundComponent` isn't just an `EditText`. It has other view objects (e.g. `TextView`), so I can't cast `v`, i.e., an `EditText`, as a `CompoundComponent`. Hmmm...

Comment: Then pass the View to CompoundComponent and compare in there. You can first pass to one CompoundView then to the other. One of them will say it's her view.